# Connecting using SSL Certificate and private Key- Push notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

I am on the verge of finally (after way too many frustrating hours trying to figure out apple's push notification C**p) running my first test push notification. However, I keep getting this problem when trying to run

```
    $ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
-cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem
```

Enter pass phrase for PushChatKey.pem:

I enter the pass phrase (99.8% sure this is correct) and I get the following error:

```
      23212:error:0906A065:PEM routines:
      PEM_do_header:bad decrypt:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src
       /crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:428:
```

I tried another password and I got this error:

```
         23213:error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:
         X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:406:
```

I think the issue is with the first error though.

This is my last step and things should start working. Does anyone know whats wrong?? Thanks!